# include LAPACK on c++ code

Tags: c++, qt, lapack

I am trying to execute following simple c++ code in Qt environment on my mac. What I want with this code is to use libraries of LAPACK for simple mathematical operations. I just considered "dot product " function to test this case and got

"Symbols not found for architecture x86_64" and 
"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) errors.

By the way, I am quite sure that i am repeating file or header file names that might cause these  same errors.

Anyone knows how to overcome this ? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>


extern "C"
{
  double ddot_ (const int*, const double*, const int*, const double*, const int*);
}



int main()
{
  std::vector<double> values(2, 1.);


  int N = 2;
  int one = 1;

  double norm = ddot_(&N, &values[0], &one, &values[0], &one);
  std::cout << "Hello world " <<norm << std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't link LAPACK

Comment: Might be, I am quite new on this, so not so sure how this works. So right now checking how to link LAPACK to C++, thanks.

Comment: Find out to link those two I should compile the code using "g++ hola.cpp -o hola" commend. But currently I am getting "can evaluate only during a QML debug session" error.

Comment: @Ceren what are you typing that into, that's not command line error I've ever seen

Comment: mmm to qml/js console on Qt... I might be doing dummy mistakes, as i said this is my first time with LAPACK and linking and stuff..

Comment: I wrote "g++ hola.cpp -o hola" to terminal as well and got again "Symbols not found for architecture x86_64" and "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) errors.

Comment: ohh i guess now i got it it has to be done with terminal window saying " clang++ -framework Accelerate hola.cpp"

Comment: I commented the `#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>`, i typed `g++ main.cpp -o main -lblas` and it compiled fine. `-lblas` is to link the blas library. If i try to compile without it, i get `undefined reference to ddot_
` Hope it helps, though my OS is Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

The function [`ddot_()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d5/df6/ddot_8f.html) is part of the Blas library. It is not a part of the Lapack library. Hence, the program using `ddot_()` should be linked to the Blas library. For instance, the c++ program you posted can be compiled by:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lblas
```

provided `#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>` is commented.